# transform table with duplicate

Tags: sql, qgis

I'm trying to transform a base with duplicates into a new base according to the attached model
impossible without duplicate
I don't see how I can do
in advance thank you for your help

original base

IDu| ID    | Information
1  |A    |1
2  |A    |2
3  |A    |3
4  |A     |4
5  |A    |5
6  |B    |1
7  |B    |2
8  |B    |3
9  |B    |4
10 |C    |1
11 |D    |1
12 |D    |2
13 |D    |3

base to reach

- ID   | Resultat/table2 | plus grand valeur
  A    |(1,2,3,4,5)      |5
  B    |(1,2,3,4)        |4
  C    |(1)              |1
  D    |(1,2,3)          |3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT
(https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php):

```
SELECT
  ID, GROUP_CONCAT(INFORMATION), COUNT(INFORMATION)
FROM
  TABLE
GROUP BY
   ID
```

Answer (score 0):

a huge thank you.
Quick and perfect response
on the other hand how I can filter to have the greatest value

Comment: You could simply "order by  COUNT(INFORMATION) desc"

Answer (score 0):

this query ranges from smallest to largest, but how to keep only the largest value

D | Resultat/table2 | **greatest value**
A |(1,2,3,4,5) **|5**
B |(1,2,3,4) **|4**
C |(1) **|1**
D |(1,2,3) **|3**

I tried, but without success

```
    SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(ID1)
from tournee_reduite
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY MAX(ID1) desc;
```

another huge thank you